# Is firewalld the same as iptables?

Tags: rhel, iptables, firewalld

I tried to close iptables on RHEL 7.2 using

`chkconfig iptables off`

> error reading information on 
>   service iptables: No such file or directory

tried `/etc/init.d/iptables stop` too, got

> -bash: /etc/init.d/iptables: No such file or directory

Then I googled it and got this :
`systemctl status firewalld`

What is the difference between iptables and firewalld? And how do you close iptables?

How can I give maximum privilege to the machine?

Comment: try to run `which iptables` as root and make sure iptables is installed in your box.

Comment: You do realize redhat 7 is using systemd instead of sysv init? chkconfig and init.d are the wrong tools now

Answer (score 11):

With RHEL 7 / CentOS 7, [firewalld](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD) was introduced to manage iptables. IMHO, firewalld is more suited for workstations than for server environments.

It is possible to go back to a more classic iptables setup. First, stop and mask the firewalld service:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl mask firewalld
```

Then, install the iptables-services package:

```
yum install iptables-services
```

Enable the service at boot-time:

```
systemctl enable iptables
```

Managing the service

```
systemctl [stop|start|restart] iptables
```

Saving your firewall rules can be done as follows:

```
service iptables save
```

or

```
/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init save
```

Answer (score 1):

Firewalld is a new iptables frontend used as the default firewall interface in RHEL 7.
Use systemctl to turn firewalld off and disable it:

```
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Comment: I have executed this command, when I executed the `iptables-save > filewall.rules`, I still can see from file **filewall.rules** there are a lot of **filewall rules** exist in it including **
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable**. What I expect is all the restrict are gone and grant the maximum privilege to this machine.

Comment: In that case, you need to flush the existing rules using either -F or --flush