# Centos 7 server iptables Active: active (exited)

Tags: centos, iptables

When I check the iptables service status it says Active (exited) why and how do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is firewalld the same as iptables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279937/is-firewalld-the-same-as-iptables)

Comment: Cannot see it is a duplicate.
Here the issue is iptables is not running proberly.

Comment: It’s not running because it’s been replaced, as described in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

That message is normal; there is no error nor anything to fix (unless you want to migrate to `firewalld`, or something). What has happened is `iptables-restore` has loaded the firewall rules, and then exited, because after loading the rules it does not need to stick around. This is typical for `Type=oneshot` services.

```
[root@redacted ~]# systemctl status iptables
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-10-04 13:14:52 UTC; 1 weeks 4 days ago
[root@redacted ~]# wc -l /etc/sysconfig/iptables
822 /etc/sysconfig/iptables
[root@redacted ~]# systemctl list-unit-files | grep ipt
iptables.service                              enabled
[root@redacted ~]# systemctl list-unit-files | grep firew
firewalld.service                             disabled
```

If you peek at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service` it's a wrapper around a shell script that (eventually) calls `iptables-restore` to load up the firewall rules from `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.

(`firewalld` is something different and may or may not be involved (it is *not* on the above firewall those commands and their outputs were copied from))