# Firewalld reject rule is present, still traffic coming in

Tags: firewalld

I asked the same question on ServerFault, 0 reactions...

We developed a simple tool that adds a reject-rule to firewalld whenever our server's SMTP port is repeatedly attacked. We discovered that some rules aren't applied, for traffic is still coming in from some IP-addresses. An example:

```
rule family="ipv4" source address="45.125.66.22" reject
rule family="ipv4" source address="45.125.66.24" reject
```

I still see traffic coming in from those addresses, so apparently the firewall lets them through.

```
28/07/2022 08:27:31   SMTP Server: Authentication failed for user monica ; connecting host 45.125.66.24
```

Rules are automatically created and activated with the following commands:

```
/bin/sudo firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=<ip-address> reject' --permanent
/bin/sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

The server is CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111... I know we should move to a different Linux distro.

What did I miss? What can I do to make this work?

---

UPDATE

The output of iptables-save:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Jul 31 16:17:13 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1160:109252]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1129:138455]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 31 16:17:13 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Jul 31 16:17:13 2022
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [1106:106324]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1130:138703]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 31 16:17:13 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Jul 31 16:17:13 2022
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1160:109252]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1132:139087]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 31 16:17:13 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Jul 31 16:17:13 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1160:109252]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1160:109252]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1135:139543]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1135:139543]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 31 16:17:13 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Jul 31 16:17:13 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [239:11084]
:INPUT ACCEPT [185:8156]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [6:440]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:440]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 31 16:17:13 2022
```

---

```
# firewall-cmd --get-zones
block dmz drop external home internal nm-shared public trusted work

# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client domino http https smtp ssh websockets
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
    rule family="ipv4" source address="45.133.1.201" reject
    rule family="ipv4" source address="31.210.20.23" reject
    ...

# firewall-cmd --list-rich-rules
... lists the same rules as above, some 520 lines
```

---

UPDATE

```
# firewall-cmd --info-service domino
domino
  ports: 1352/tcp
  protocols: 
  source-ports: 
  modules: 
  destination: 
  includes: 
  helpers: 

# firewall-cmd --info-service websockets
websockets
  ports: 3000-3029/tcp
  protocols: 
  source-ports: 
  modules: 
  destination: 
  includes: 
  helpers:
```

Comment: What does `iptables-save` show for the firewall rules? (It might be better to feed bad IP addresses into an ipsets list, not to add them as individual firewall rules, which would change the problem into "how to use ipsets with firewalld".)

Comment: As I understand the documentation [Using and configuring firewalld](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/using-and-configuring-firewalld_configuring-and-managing-networking), wouldn't it be necessary to add the rule to a zone? Is there a default zone?

Comment: I updated the question with the output of iptables-save. As for the zone suggestion: serious firewalld noob here... no clue... hope to get suggestions from you.

Comment: Instead of the `iptables-save` output, can you have a look into `firewall-cmd --get-zones`, `firewall-cmd --list-all` and `firewall-cmd --list-rich-rules`? Probably the public zone should have the rule included `firewall-cmd --list-rich-rules --zone public`.

Comment: Would it be possible to block SMTP for public connections from outside in general and allow SMTP traffic for internal or trusted management network only?

Comment: No. Incoming mail is allowed, and anyone trying to gain access is to be blocked forever. I missed the —zone public, will check now.

Comment: Same list of rules.

Comment: You could try to add the source IP into the `drop` zone, `firewall-cmd --change-source=<ip> --zone=drop && firewall-cmd --change-source=<ip> --zone=drop --permanent`. Source: "[_fail2ban-firewalld on Linux RedHat 8_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70523740/6771046)"

Answer (score 1):

In RHEL/CentOS 8 and RHEL 9, `firewalld` uses `nftables` instead of classic `iptables`. That's why your `iptables-save` looks like you have no rules at all.

To actually see your `nftables` firewall rules, run:

```
nft list ruleset
```

It is possible to manually create a set of `nftables` rules that will have a higher priority than the rules created by `firewalld`, so if someone has configured some rules (e.g. via `cockpit` I see is allowed in your `firewalld` configuration, or by manually editing `/etc/nftables/main.nft`) in addition to what `firewalld` is doing, it will be important to look at the whole ruleset to understand the order in which the various rules are being processed.

If a manually-created filter table contains a rule to allow SMTP and that table has higher priority than the filter tables created by `firewalld`, that might explain why your `firewalld` configuration is ineffective in blocking SMTP from those source addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the nftables, which actually only complicates matters for me. Maybe I'd better start from scratch. Could it be that the firewall gets confused over this: I have a rule to reject all 45.0.0.0/8 addresses, and then I had to accept one specific address in that range?

Comment: By the way, I'm the only person managing this server, and AFAIK I applied all rules using firewall-cmd, no manual changes to main.nft or so, no cockpit, no 'someones' around. ;-)

Comment: Removed the rule created with firewall-cmd --zone=drop --add-source=45.0.0.0/8 , Was it the --zone=drop that I should have left out? Every 5 or 6 minutes a new connect request used to come in, haven't seen one for the last 10 minutes... seems like progress!

Comment: If you have no network interfaces assigned to the `drop` zone, that should have had no effect at all. But I see two services whose contents are not immediately obvious to me: `domino` and `websockets`. `domino` suggests Lotus Domino, which has SMTP functionality of its own, and so its service definition might be relevant - so please add the outputs of `firewall-cmd --info-service domino` and `firewall-cmd --info-service websockets` to the original post?

Comment: Correct, but nothing really special going on there. On the very positive side: from the moment I removed the 45.0.0.0 rule, all reject rules seem to be functional again. I wanted to block all traffic from 45.0.0.0/8, so every additional reject rule is superfluous. Should I have left out the --zone=drop ?? Zones are far to difficult for mere mortals who dabble in Unix/Linux since 1977... ;-)

Comment: @D.Bugger  just use iptables directly, why not? It's much cleaner

Comment: I don't object iptables, I just wanted to try to do the "right" thing, and the things right. I've used iptables before, but ipset is new to me. I'll be reading up on those two in due course.

Comment: How much iptables rules you have? ipset is optional. 100 rules for iptables is not a problem.

Comment: @D.Bugger Can you post output of nft list ruleset here or pastebin?

Comment: How many iptables rules? No clue, really. The nft ruleset output you can find here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7b8bitv3kqe742x/ruleset.gz?dl=0

Comment: @D.Bugger  in rules generated by firewalld, chain for reject,drop rules in INPUT placed after established,related rule, established connections accepted first. So reject rules may no effect until connection to your server will be closed explicitly or by timeout.

Comment: So attacker may brute your until tcp connection will be not closed by attacker or by you server. So firewalld generate badly designed rulset. In PREROUTING there is no such problem so 
ip saddr 45.0.0.0/8 goto mangle_PRE_drop
ip saddr 82.65.28.0/24 goto mangle_PRE_drop
should work but there is another mess - mangle_PRE_drop (and next jumped chains) has no rules at all, so it do nothing and accept.

Comment: As for now

rule family="ipv4" source address="45.125.66.22" reject

rule family="ipv4" source address="45.125.66.24" reject

should work. If not, try to delete connection from these IPs by conntrack -D -s 45.125.66.22. You should add your rules into PREROUTING with firewalld somehow  so they take immediate effect.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case you don't need rich rules nor reload the firewalld rules.

It's sufficient to add these sources to the firewalld block zone:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=block --add-source=45.125.66.22
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=block --add-source=45.125.66.22
firewall-cmd --zone=block --add-source=45.125.66.24
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=block --add-source=45.125.66.24
```

NB: This doesn't kill already established connection!

You can kill those like this:

```
ss -K dst 45.125.66.22
ss -K dst 45.125.66.24
```

Answer (score 0):

firewalld just generate nothing for some wired reason. As result kernel accept all incoming traffic.

Just use and learn plain iptables and ipset instead of firewalld mess - that will be much more efficient and streightforward.

For fast start just add rules like

```
iptables -A INPUT -s bad_ip -j DROP
```

and disable firewalld.

Then evolve you rules for your task. stateful rules, connection tracking, ipset, ports ...

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. Furthermore it is based on an opinion and not covered by any fact.

Comment: Facts. firewalld mostly is just another wrapping tool to generate iptables/nftables rules, isn't it? It has wired terminology for network concepts like zones and ports. It has limited capabilities compared with full power of using iptables and ipset. It badly suited for routers task.

Comment: I do not find that [the concept of zones](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Firewalld#Which_zones_are_available?) has a wired terminology. That's just my opinion. It might be that only a subset of capabilities in comparison with iptables is available. However, here the question is just about very common and basic task, simple reject of traffic from defined sources. It seems also the question is regarding servers and not (dedicated) routers.

Comment: Furthermore, changing a system configuration can result into further dependencies, complexity and side effects. Therefore I do not prefer one over other ... [firewalld vs iptables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279937/), [firewalld vs iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/671970/). So it will depend on the OP what suits more for him.

Comment: I haven't "ruled" out iptables yet, I'm trying with firewalld first, and if it gets overly complex, I may revert to iptables. Thanks.